# In LINQtoSQL, how can I update child relationships by editing the parent model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

This is my first attempt at updating a database using LINQtoSQL. At least, it's my first if you don't count the tutorials I've followed. Unfortunately, The tutorials that I have found don't offer much more than updating a single table. I'm attempting to update a DB Model that's a bit more complex.

I have a `Stream` table:

```
[Table]
public class Stream
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public long StreamID { get; set; }

    /** Other columns removed for brevity **/

    // relationship:
    private EntitySet<Stream2FieldTypes> _Stream2FieldTypes;
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(Storage = "_Stream2FieldTypes", OtherKey = "StreamID")]
    public EntitySet<Stream2FieldTypes> Stream2FieldTypes
    {
        get { return this._Stream2FieldTypes; }
        set { this._Stream2FieldTypes.Assign(value); }
    }
```

And I have a `Stream2FieldTypes` table:

```
[Table]
public class Stream2FieldTypes
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public long s2fID { get; set; }
    public long StreamID { get; set; }     // FK

    /** other columns removed for brevity **/

    // relationship (one Stream2FieldTypes to many Streams) 
    private EntitySet<Stream> _Stream;
    [Association(Storage = "_Stream", ThisKey = "StreamID")]
    public EntitySet<Stream> Stream
    {
        get { return this._Stream; }
        set { this._Stream.Assign(value); }
    }
```

Now, I am trying to update the model so I can send updates to the repository to persist to `DataContext`. I can't update `Stream.Stream2FieldTypes` because the `get` is set to a private `EntitySet`.

How do I update `Stream.Stream2FieldTypes` when I can't change `Stream.Stream2FieldTypes` because it's a private EntitySet<>?

### Edit: psuedo code

Basically, I think I should be able to update the `Stream` and `Stream2FieldTypes` tables by using a command in my Edit Action like this:

```
myRepository.SaveStream(stream);
```

I have been trying to do something like this:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Convert StreamEditModel to Stream
            var stream = new Genesis.Domain.Entities.Stream
            {
                StreamID = form.StreamID,
                StreamUrl = form.StreamUrl,
                StreamName = form.StreamName,
                StreamBody = form.StreamBody,
                StreamTitle = form.StreamTitle,
                StreamKeywords = form.StreamKeywords,
                StreamDescription = form.StreamDescription,
                Stream2FieldTypes = new EntitySet<Stream2FieldTypes>()
            };

            // Loop to convert Stream2FieldTypes to Steam2FieldTypesEditModel
            foreach (var item in form.Stream2FieldTypes)
            {
                var fieldTypeEntry = new Stream2FieldTypes
                {
                    FieldTypeID = item.FieldTypeID,
                    s2fID = item.s2fID,
                    s2fIsRequired = item.s2fIsRequired,
                    s2fLabel = item.s2fLabel,
                    StreamID = item.StreamID,
                };
                stream.Stream2FieldTypes.Add(fieldTypeEntry); // Add to list
            }

            genesisRepository.SaveStream(stream);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else 
        {
            return View(form);
        }
```

When I try to run this code, I get this error:

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 58:         {
>
> Line 59:             get { return this._Stream2FieldTypes; }
>
> line with error: Line 60:             set { this._Stream2FieldTypes.Assign(value); }
>
> Line 61:         }
>
> Line 62:

Comment: Please show some (pseudo)code of what you try to achieve, because I'm not sure if I follow you.

Comment: I don't know if a get you very well, but you are actually able to update Stream.Stream2FieldTypes because it is a public property that allows you to access the underlying _Steam2FieldTypes EntitySet. I would recommend you to use Entity Framework instead of LinQ To SQL because Microsoft has put LinQ To SQL in maintenance mode and they are only going to continue developing EF further as their official ORM instead

Comment: @Vintharas:  LINQ to SQL is still fully-supported.  StackExchange uses it.  I doubt the OP is keen to re-engineer his entire solution.

Comment: @Steven - Please see above for additional code.
@Vintharas - I had considered that, but according to StevenSanderson's book (Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework) page 55: "I'm aware that some developers have expressed concerns that MS might depricate LINQ to SQL in favor of Entity Framework. However, MS included and enhanced LINQ to SQL in .NET 4, so these fears cannot be entirely justified."

Comment: I'm reading that book also! It's great, isn't it? :)

Comment: @Dave: I agree with you that I wouldn't re-engineer an entire solution already built upon LINQ to SQL. However, if you are starting to learn LINQ to SQL wouldn't be wiser perhaps to put your effort behind EF rather than on LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @Vintharas - I do like the book alot... If there was a resource like that with Entity framework examples I probalby would have put my energy into that. But, anyway... Does anyone have a comment regarding a solution to my question? :-)

Comment: I am sorry, I've been thinking but I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge in LinQ To SQL to solve your problem! :_

Comment: The problem quakkels has with LINQ to SQL is exactly the same as he would have had when is was using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SaveStream` method, you set the `StreamID` property like this `StreamID = item.StreamID`. Because you have a Stream id I expect you are trying to change an existing `Stream` class. However, when looking at your code, you are creating a new one. I think the problem you are experiencing is caused by that.

What you should do is the following:

- Differentiate between creating a new one and mutating an existing entity.
- Try to minimize the use of ID properties as much as you can. Work with the entities itself. This makes your code much cleaner and readable. (I always make the ID properties internal and the `EntitySet` and `EntityRef` public).

For instance, I think your `SaveStream` should look more like the next code. If you look closely, this code lacks lines such as:

- `FieldTypeID = item.FieldTypeID` and
- `StreamID = form.StreamID`.

This is because this simply wont work. You need to retrieve an existing entity from the database first and update it. You can't create a new object, set its ID to an existing record in the database and expect LINQ to SQL to update that record for you. This is not how LINQ to SQL is designed.

Here is an example of what might work for you:

```
public void SaveStream(StreamEditModel stream)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (stream.Id == 0)
    {
        CreateStream(stream);
    }
    else
    {
        UpdateStream(stream);
    }
}

private void CreateStream(StreamEditModel form)
{
    var stream = new Stream();

    FillStream(stream, form);

    UpdateStream2FieldTypes(stream, form);

    genesisRepository.SubmitChanges();
}

private void UpdateStream(StreamEditModel form)
{
    var stream = genesisRepository.GetById(stream.StreamID);

    FillStream(stream, form);

    UpdateStream2FieldTypes(stream, form);

    genesisRepository.SubmitChanges();
}

private void FillStream(Stream stream, StreamEditModel form)
{
    stream.StreamUrl = form.StreamUrl;
    stream.StreamName = form.StreamName;
    stream.StreamBody = form.StreamBody;
    stream.StreamTitle = form.StreamTitle;
    stream.StreamKeywords = form.StreamKeywords;
    stream.StreamDescription = form.StreamDescription;
}

private void UpdateStream2FieldTypes(Stream stream,
    StreamEditModel form)
{
    var typesToDelete =
        from type in stream.Stream2FieldTypes
        let ids = form.Stream2FieldTypes.Select(t => t.FieldTypeID)
        where !ids.Contains(type.FieldTypeID)
        select type;

    genesisRepository.RemoveStream2FieldTypes(typesToDelete);

    var typesToAdd =
        from type in form.Stream2FieldTypes
        where type.FieldTypeID == 0
        select CreateStream2FieldTypes(type);

    foreach (var typeToAdd in typesToAdd)
    {
        stream.Stream2FieldTypes.Add(typeToAdd);
    }

    var formTypesToUpdate = 
        from type in form.Stream2FieldTypes
        where type.FieldTypeID != 0
        select type;

    foreach (var modelToUpdate in formTypesToUpdate)
    {
        var typeToUpdate = stream.Stream2FieldTypes.Single(
            t => t.FieldTypeID == modelToUpdate.FieldTypeID);

        FillStream2FieldTypes(typeToUpdate, typeToUpdate);
    }
}

private static  Stream2FieldTypes CreateStream2FieldTypes(
    Stream2FieldTypesEditModel form)
{
    var fieldType = new Stream2FieldTypes();

    FillStream2FieldTypes(fieldType, form);

    return fieldType;
}

private static void FillStream2FieldTypes(
    Stream2FieldTypes type, 
    Stream2FieldTypesEditModel item)
{
    type.s2fID = item.s2fID;
    type.s2fIsRequired = item.s2fIsRequired;
    type.s2fLabel = item.s2fLabel;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Wow - thank you for all the work. It'll take me a while to wade through this though :-)

Comment: Quick question: Do you think it's okay to delete all `Stream2FieldTypes` records for `stream` and then we can just perform a `CreateStream2FieldTypes` instead of figuring out which get deleted, which get updated, and which get created?

Comment: If `Stream2FieldTypes` is not a root of some complicated graph, you don't have any triggers on that type, don't have any auto generated fields in the database that might get lost and it doesn't have any negative performance implications for you.... it might be okay ;-) You’re the only one who can tell.